# Install error custom package with devtools/bitbucket

Tags: r, bitbucket, rstudio, devtools

I'm completely new to R so this may be a simple fix. I'm trying to install my company's package and I'm getting the following error.

```
> devtools::install_bitbucket("owac/owactools", auth_user = 
"username", password = "password")
Downloading bitbucket repo owac/owactools@master
Installing owactools
"C:/Users/SPENCE~1/DOCUME~1/R/R-33~1.0/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file
--no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD  \
INSTALL "C:/Users/spencer-miller/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpsXEvW5
/devtools1ca063f850e1/owac-owactools-d9441106847e"  \
--library="C:/Users/spencer-miller/Documents/R/R-3.3.0/library" 
--install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'owactools' ...
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** tests
** preparing package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = 
vI[[i]]) : 
there is no package called 'ggplot2'
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'owactools'
* removing 'C:/Users/spencer-miller/Documents/R/R-3.3.0/library
/owactools'
Error: Command failed (1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to download the package **ggplot2** via:

```
install.packages(c("ggplot2"))
```

The error message

> there is no package called 'ggplot2'

indicates this.

Comment: Actually, that should not be necessary. `install_bitbucket` calls `install` internally, which tries "to install dependencies of the package from CRAN, if they're not already installed". This always has worked without problems for my packages on bitbucket.

Comment: I assumed the ggplot2 issue was a result of the latter issue. But installing it separately fixed the issue. Thank you, J_F.